# While calling method by passing Long value, why Float argument method got executed?

Tags: scala

```
class Demo  
{
     def m1(a: Float) 
    {
        println("m1 Float-arg method");
    }
}

object Demo1     
{
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        val demo = new Demo

        demo.m1(10f)
        demo.m1(65l)
    }
}
```

output:

m1 Float-arg method

m1 Float-arg method

1. As per above example, i'm calling m1(65l) method with Long value, but i didn't defined m1 method with Long argument, So i expected error,
2. but m1 method with Float argument method got executed for m1(56l) method call?

How the internal flow will be?

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the `Long.scala` companion object there is an implicit conversion:

`implicit def long2float(x: Long): Float = x.toFloat`

Also in the `Predef.scala` there are conversions for autoboxing and autounboxing:

`implicit def long2Long(x: Long)           = java.lang.Long.valueOf(x)`

So first your `65l` is autoboxed to `Long(65)` and then converted to `Float`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `Long` implementation of `Scala`:

```
object Long extends AnyValCompanion {
  /** The smallest value representable as a Long. */
  final val MinValue = java.lang.Long.MIN_VALUE

  /** The largest value representable as a Long. */
  final val MaxValue = java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE

  /** Transform a value type into a boxed reference type.
   *
   *  Runtime implementation determined by `scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToLong`.         See [[https://github.com/scala/scala     src/library/scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.java]].
   *
   *  @param  x   the Long to be boxed
   *  @return     a java.lang.Long offering `x` as its underlying value.
   */
  def box(x: Long): java.lang.Long = java.lang.Long.valueOf(x)

  /** Transform a boxed type into a value type.  Note that this
   *  method is not typesafe: it accepts any Object, but will throw
   *  an exception if the argument is not a java.lang.Long.
   *
   *  Runtime implementation determined by     `scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong`. See [[https://github.com/scala/scala src/library/scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.java]].
   *
   *  @param  x   the java.lang.Long to be unboxed.
   *  @throws     ClassCastException  if the argument is not a java.lang.Long
   *  @return     the Long resulting from calling longValue() on `x`
   */
  def unbox(x: java.lang.Object): Long =     x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long].longValue()

  /** The String representation of the scala.Long companion object. */
  override def toString = "object scala.Long"
  /** Language mandated coercions from Long to "wider" types. */
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def long2float(x: Long): Float = x.toFloat
  implicit def long2double(x: Long): Double = x.toDouble
}
```

As you see at the end, there are two implicit methods. `long2float` method implicitly converts `long` to `float`.

When you prove a `long` to a method accepting `float`, this method is used for conversion.